# Всем доброго дня суток, вопрос по библиотекам

Tags: reactjs

На проекте есть своя библиотека, когда вносятся изменения в нее они не появляются локально, что бы они появились я должен отправить их на серв а потом снова стянуть все изменения и только тогда они отоброзятся в приложении. как можно обойти эту проблему и видеть все изменения сразу локально? А то разрабатывать что-то крайне неудобно. Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

В package.json прописать ссылку на библиотеку по протоколу `file://`. Впрочем, могут вылезти свои нюансы.